# Is there a way to see which Project Wizard was used to create a given Eclipse Project?

Tags: java, eclipse, project, wizard

Every time I start working on a new J2EE web application, I need to create the various Eclipse projects that I'll fill up. This includes the top-level project that generates the EAR, a WAR project, etc. I usually only have to do this every couple of months, so I never remember the exact steps - specifically, which Eclipse Project Wizards to use for each project in the webapp.

I have enough old J2EE projects laying around that they could serve as good reference if only I could actually see which Wizard created them. Is there a way to recover this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best system I found since asking this is to look at a project's facets. If needed I can compare an existing Eclipse project to a newly created one from the wizard; if the facets are identical, then I've (re)found the right wizard.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it is possible.

What I would suggest is to use Maven. It has archetypes to automatically create specific types of projects. It is even easier in Eclipse with m2eclipse plugin. Take a look [here](http://www.sonatype.com/books/m2eclipse-book/reference/eclipse-sect-creating-project.html#eclipse-sect-m2e-create-archetype)

Comment: I'm really not looking for a new system.

Comment: It is not new... almost nothing will change for you if you developing in Eclipse. Things will become even easier :)

...and bears will stop eating you :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that information is stored anywhere.

However you can look at the .project xml file that every project has in Eclipse. You want to look at the <natures> element specifically, that will give you a hint of what type of project you want to create.